# Find the abs max and min values of $f(x,y,z)=x-2y+3z$ on the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}+ \frac{z^2}{2}-1=0$

Tags: calculus

How do I do the following

Find the abs max and min values of $f(x,y,z)=x-2y+3z$ on the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}+ \frac{z^2}{2}-1=0$

I found my two gradient ofcourse.

$<1,-2,3>$ $<\frac{1x}{3},\frac{2y}{3},z>$

Then I set up my system of equations

$1=\frac{1}{3}x \lambda$

$-2=\frac{2y}{3} \lambda$

$3=z\lambda$

$\frac{x^2}{6}+\frac{y^2}{3}+ \frac{z^2}{2}-1=0$

Then I solved for x and got $\frac{3}{\lambda}=x$

$y=\frac{-3}{\lambda}$

$z=\frac{3}{\lambda}$

Plug it in back to my equation

I get

$\frac{9}{\lambda^26}+\frac{18}{\lambda^26}+\frac{54}{\lambda^26}-1=0$

$\lambda^2=\frac{6}{81}$

But I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Assuming the arithmetic at the end is correct, then $\lambda = \pm \frac{\sqrt{6}}{9}$. You get two extreme points. Plug them in the objective function to see which one corresponds to absolute max and which one to absolute min.

Comment: You can save yourself a little work, since your results for $ \ \lambda \ $ tells you that $ \ x = z = -y \ . $  Now you know that $ \ \frac{x^2}{6} \ + \ \frac{x^2}{3} \ + \ \frac{x^2}{2} = 1 \ .$

Comment: So that means that one of my points is (1,-1,1)

Comment: That looks to be correct.  I'll mention that, since the Lagrange-multiplier method looks for tangent planes to constraint surfaces in problems like this, for a surface with symmetry about the origin, the minimum and maximum values of the function will be located at points on a line through the origin.

Comment: Hmm so in that if it is symetrical I multiply by (-1)

Comment: To get (-1,1,-1) ? for my plug in points

Comment: Yes, just so!  Now you can calculate the extremal values of $ \ f(x,y,z) \ . $

Comment: I was going to say that it wouldn't have been wrong to work with $ \ \lambda \ $ , it's just somewhat more work to get to the answer.  (Although your equation should read, I believe, $ \ \frac{9}{\lambda^26} \ + \ \frac{18}{\lambda^26} \ + \ \frac{27}{\lambda^26} \ - \ 1 \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ \lambda^2 \ = \ \frac{6}{54} \ = \ \frac{1}{9} \ . $ )